# Do not escape links contains in a text

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

I created a function allowing to detect a link in a text. The problem is that I arrive not at the poster correctly seen that blade {{}} escape from the HTML code. What solution would you propose me? 
sorry for my bad english.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can tell blade not to escape your variable like this.

```
{!! $htmlVariable !!}
```

Learn how to use Blade here: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/blade

**For Laravel 4:**

```
{{{ $htmlVariable }}}
```

Comment: This will definitely work but you could be creating XSS vunerabilities. I think you'd be better using a HTML purifier for that specific output and using the {!! !!} syntax https://github.com/alexusmai/laravel-purifier. You can then specify allowed tags and ensure tags like <script> are not permitted

Comment: @GuerthManzala Then please, accept my answer. Thanks :)